# Parse Live Query Memory Leak

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse live query (in js and vue.js) to update/replace an array on each create. I noticed however that live query is causing a memory leak. As I'm running 3 live queries at at time, after day of running I get up to +2GB of memory and and error page with "out of memory".

Here an example of how I open one of my subscriptions.

```
 Parse.initialize(this.parse.initialize)
        Parse.serverURL = this.parse.serverURL

        const snapshots = Parse.Object.extend("snapshots");
        const query = new Parse.Query(snapshots)
        const subscriptionSnapshots = await query.subscribe()

        subscriptionSnapshots.on('open', () => {
            console.log(' -> Snapshots subscription opened');
        });
```

I don't know if it's related, but in my browser console I see the following alerts

```
[Violation] 'message' handler took <N>ms
parse.min.js:13 [Violation] 'message' handler took 164ms
```

Any ideas where the leak comes from and how I can stop it ?

Comment: Is this memory leak happening on server or client? Can you reproduce the memory leak only using this code that you shared?

Comment: It happens on the client and yes only using this code. As an example, after 30mn testing it took up 400mb of memory.

Comment: How are you testing it? Do you have only this code on the browser, open it a single time, wait 20min, and have the 400mb memory problem?